# How to set a struct's pointer to a value in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Given:

```
struct phoneNum{
   int phoneNumber;
   struct number *next;
};

struct phoneNum numbers [50];

for(y=0; y < 50; y++){
   numbers[y].phoneNumber = 0;
   numbers[y].next = -1;
}
```

How do I set the pointer for my struct to a value?  I've been trying to set it -1 for testing, but I get errors when I try to compile.  Eventually, I need to have that pointer, next, point to another phoneNum struct.  I'm trying to form an array-based linked lists of all theses structs.

Comment: What is `struct number *next` in the definition of `struct phoneNum` ?

Comment: Surely the `next` field should be of type `struct phoneNum *`.

Comment: May be he meant struct phoneNum *next?

Comment: Explain in your question what exactly you mean by `array-based linked lists of all theses structs`, and you might get an answer that refers to what you are ultimately trying to achieve (rather than an answer that would simply tell you how to fix those one or two compilation errors in your code).

Answer (score 2):

1) since next is a pointer so you can assign numbers[y].next = NULL

2) In the question you have mentioned "next, point to another phoneNum struct" then the structure should be modified

```
struct phoneNum
{
   int phoneNumber;
   struct phoneNum *next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

set 'numbers[y].next' to the value of a ptr, and NULL is an acceptable value:

```
   numbers[y].next = NULL;
```

-1 is NOT a valid value for a ptr.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `int` to a `struct number *`, thats the error you are getting. Try `numbers[y].next = (struct number *)(-1);` instead.

But this kind of use of pointers is irregular. A pointer that is "not set" should be set to `NULL`, not some random number you take out of your pocket.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend casting `-1` to a pointer.  That clearly wasn't the OP's intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
// to construct a linked list you should add link pointer with a same type of your structure
struct phoneNum{
   int phoneNumber;
   struct phoneNum *next;
};

struct phoneNum numbers [50];

for(y=0; y < 50; y++){
   numbers[y].phoneNumber = 0;
// a pointer must be set to NULL, do not set to int "-1"
   numbers[y].next = NULL;
}
```